# getting the sum of the out put in unix

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to get the sum of my output in bash shell using only awk. One of the problems I am getting is that I only need to use awk in this.

This is the code I am using for getting the output:
`awk '{print substr($7, 9, 4)}' emp.txt`

This is the output I am getting: `(output omitted)
7606
6498
7947
4044
1657
3872
4834
8463
9280
2789
9104`

this is how I am trying to do the sum of the numbers: `awk '(s = s + substr($7, 9, 4)) {print s}' emp.txt`

The problem is that it is not giving me the right output (which should be `9942686`) but instead giving me the series sum (as shown below).

`(output omitted)
9890696
9898643
9902687
9904344
9908216
9913050
9921513
9930793
9933582
9942686`

Am I using the code the wrong way? Or is there any other method of doing it with awk and I am doing it the wrong way?

Here is the sample file I am working on:

`Brynlee Watkins F 55 Married 2016 778-555-6498 62861
Malcolm Curry M 24 Married 2016 604-555-7947 54647
Aylin Blake F 45 Married 2015 236-555-4044 80817
Mckinley Hodges F 50 Married 2015 604-555-1657 46316
Rylan Dorsey F 51 Married 2017 778-555-3872 77160
Taylor Clarke M 23 Married 2015 604-555-4834 46624
Vivaan Hooper M 26 Married 2016 778-555-8463 80010
Gibson Rowland M 42 Married 2017 236-555-9280 59874
Alyson Mahoney F 51 Single 2017 778-555-2789 71394
Catalina Frazier F 53 Married 2016 604-555-9104 79364`

EDIT: I want to get the sum of the numbers that are repeating in the output. Let's say the repeating numbers are `4826` and `0028` in the output and both of them repeated 2 times. I only want the sum of these numbers (each repetition must be counted as the individual. hence these are counted as 4). So the desired output for these 4 numbers shall be `9708`

`Will Duffy M 33 Single 2017 236-555-4826 47394
Nolan Reed M 27 Single 2015 604-555-0028 46622
Anya Horn F 54 Married 2017 236-555-4826 73270
Cynthia Davenport F 29 Married 2015 778-555-0028 59687
Oscar Medina M 43 Married 2016 778-555-7864 73688
Angelina Herrera F 37 Married 2017 604-555-7910 82061
Peyton Reyes F 35 Married 2017 236-555-8046 51920`

Comment: Is it really `(s = s + substr($7, 9, 4))` in your code? This is really a pattern that is evaluated per each line (so luckily it does the calculation you need). The outer parentheses should probably be braces instead.

Comment: So it is not the way how is it done? is there a better way somehow using awk?

Answer (score 1):

```
END { print s }
```

Since you only need the total sum printed once, do it under the END pattern.

```
awk '{s = s + substr($7, 9, 4)} END {print s}' emp.txt
```

Comment: I have tried it before using END pattern, and it showed me a syntax error near the starting of END

Comment: Well, if it was that parenthesized expression before END, then it might result in error for it was two patterns in a row and awk usually does not permit such constructs (implicit action is only invoked when the whole script is but a single pattern). Change parentheses into braces and put END back and then see what happens.

Comment: Thanks very much sir! That worked great for me! Just curious if I can put a condition as if I only wanted the sum of those numbers which are repeating in this output.

Comment: @GaganpreetSinghMaan, please post example of it once in your post with CODE TAGS.

Comment: @bipli please see the edited question and the sample file with repeated last 4 digits

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you. It will look always look for last digits after `-`:

```
awk -F' |-' '{sum+=$(NF-1)} END{print sum}'  Input_file
```

***EDIT:***

```
awk -F' |-' '
{
  ++a[$(NF-1)];
  b[$(NF-1)]=b[$(NF-1)]?b[$(NF-1)]+$(NF-1):$(NF-1)
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    if(a[i]>1){
     print i,b[i]}
}}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
4826 9652
0028 56
```

Comment: That works great! Just a few addition: I onlyu wanted the sum of numbers that are repeating in the end... so is there any command I can use in addition to get that>

Comment: @GaganpreetSinghMaan, could you please do let me know which repeating numbers you are referring here?

Comment: please see the edited question and the sample file with repeated last 4 digits

Comment: @GaganpreetSinghMaan, please check my EDIT code now and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @GaganpreetSinghMaan, Veere, could you please do lemme know if this helped you?